# I am trying a simple query with in parameter with mysql 5.5 through jdbc code

Tags: mysql, jdbc

```
String sql="select * from matrix where metric_name in(?)";
PreparedStatement st1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
st1.setString(1,"NO_OF_ORDERS");
resultSet = st1.executeQuery(sql);
 while (resultSet.next()) {
}
```

The same query works fine with mysql 5.7 but I am not able to find the issue.
How do pass in parameters in mysql 5.5 from jdbc

**Error is :**
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?)' at line 1

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?)' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call `executeQuery(String)` on a `PreparedStatement`, you should call `executeQuery()` instead. This is explicitly disallowed by the JDBC api, but only goes wrong by accident (due to the syntax error) with MySQL Connector/J.

Note that your current query is the equivalent of:

```
select * from matrix where metric_name = ?
```

I don't see a reason why you'd use `IN` here.