# Error while inserting into MYSQL database in JavaFX

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, insert

I have a problem inserting data into MYSQL database. Using code below I get an error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?)' at line 1
```

CODE:

```
public void signUpUser(Connection conn, String userName, String password) {

        String queryString = "INSERT INTO USERS (USER_ALIAS, USER_PASS) VALUES (?,?)";
        try {
            preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, userName);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate(queryString);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But with this code the insert works normally:

```
public void signUpUser(Connection conn, String userName, String password) {
        String queryString = "INSERT INTO USERS (USER_ALIAS, USER_PASS) VALUES ('"+userName+"', '"+password+"')";

        try {
            preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate(queryString);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I want to know why does it throws error while using first part of code
Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am trying a simple query with in parameter with mysql 5.5 through jdbc code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779461/i-am-trying-a-simple-query-with-in-parameter-with-mysql-5-5-through-jdbc-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to execute update with the string although you have already created the statement.

You have to use:

```
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```